# Flask get data from drop-down into sqlite

Tags: javascript, python, html, sqlite, flask

I'm completely new to the flask, and really am completely lost with how to approach this.

```
    <tr>
        <th>Anmerkungen</th>
            <td type="text" name="kunden_anmerkungen" id="kunden_anmerkungen" ><textarea rows="3" cols="30"></textarea></td><br>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Lektor</th>
            <td>
                <select name="lektor" id="lektor">
                {% for user in users %}
                        <option value= "{{ user['username'] }}" name="lektor" id="lektor">{{ user['username'] }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </td>
    </tr>
```

I try to get the data from the drop-down menu to be inserted into an SQLite database. All other fields in the DP are updated. But the Lektor field can't be read.

```
kunden_anmerkungen = request.form.get("kunden_anmerkungen")
lektor = request.form.get("lektor")
db.execute("UPDATE kunden SET ...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does "_the Lektor field can't be read_" mean this `lektor = request.form.get("lektor")` returns `None`? Based on everything I have to assume about the unseen code, I immediately suspect invalid HTML. Perhaps see if it [validates](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).

Answer (score 0):

you should add the full code involved to this, however it seems like the issue is between the select and the option tag.

Try this:

```
 <tr>
        <th>Anmerkungen</th>
            <td type="text" name="kunden_anmerkungen" id="kunden_anmerkungen" ><textarea rows="3" cols="30"></textarea></td><br>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Lektor</th>
            <td>
                <select name="lektor" id="lektor">
                {% for user in users %}
                        <option value= "{{ user['username'] }}" id="lektor">{{ user['username'] }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </td>
    </tr>
```

Basically there is name in the option and name in the 'select' tag which may cause issue.
But again if this doesn't work then add the full code because how you set the Database, the flask app or the HTML may change everything

Also Important, I don't see the  tag in the HTML file ?